# Getting memory limit exceed error on App Engine when doing a db clean

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have the following code that I run everyweek through a cron job to clear older db entries. After 3-4 minutes I get `Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 189 MB after servicing 1006 requests total`.

Then there is this message also `While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.` Below is the clear code.

```
def clean_user_older_stories(user):
  stories = Story.query(Story.user==user.key).order(-Story.created_time).fetch(offset=200, limit=500, keys_only=True)
  print 'stories len ' + str(len(stories))
  ndb.delete_multi(stories)


def clean_older_stories():
  for user in User.query():
    clean_user_older_stories(user)
```

I guess there is a better way to deal with this. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of [In-Context Cache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext)

> With executing long-running queries in background tasks, it's possible for the in-context cache to consume large amounts of memory. This is because the cache keeps a copy of every entity that is retrieved or stored in the current context.

Try disabling cache

> To avoid memory exceptions in long-running tasks, you can disable the cache or set a policy that excludes whichever entities are consuming the most memory.

```
ctx = ndb.get_context
ctx.set_cache_policy(False)
ctx.set_memcache_policy(False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making your User query a `keys_only` query? You are not using any User properties besides the key and this would help cut down on memory usage.

You should page through large queries by setting a page_size and using a [Cursor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors).

Your handler can invoke itself through the task queue with the next cursor until the end of the result set is reached. Optionally you can use the [deferred API cut down on boilerplate code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema) for this kind of task.

That being said, the 'join' your are doing between User and Store could make this challenging. I would page through Users first as it seems from what you have described Users will grow overtime but number of Stories per User is limited.